# mongodb connection error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am getting following error while connecting to mongodb using rails console :

**Getting Error Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No server is available matching preference: # using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015**

This happens when I switch my rails application.
It is working fine in another rails application(which I was working on for a while) console but when I try to use it in another rails application it gives above error.

I have checked my mongo server it is running and I have also checked my mongoid.yml file configuration. Everything seems fine.

I am a newbie on rails.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance